# Does $f^{-1}(\{x\}) \in \mathcal{L}$ for all $x$ imply that $f$ is Lebesgue-measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Problem: Let $\Omega = \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\mathcal{L}(\bar{\mathbb{R}})$ the Lebesgue sigma-algebra. Let $A \not\in \mathcal{L}(\bar{\mathbb{R}})$ and
\begin{equation}
f(x)=
\begin{cases} 
x & , x \in A \\
-x & , x \not\in A
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Then $f^{-1}(\{x\}) \in \mathcal{L}(\bar{\mathbb{R}})$ for all $x \in \bar{\mathbb{R}}$, but $f$ fails to be Lebesgue-measurable.

My Approach: First, $f^{-1}(\{x\}) \subset \{-x,x\}$, hence in $\mathcal{L}(\bar{\mathbb{R}})$ for all $x \in \bar{\mathbb{R}}$. Next, for $B \in \mathcal{B}(\bar{\mathbb{R}})$, $f^{-1}(B) = (A \cap B) \cup (A^c \cap -B)$. Suppose that $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{L}$ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}(\bar{\mathbb{R}})$. In particular for $B=[0,\infty]$, thus $A \cap [0,\infty] = f^{-1}([0,\infty]) \cap [0,\infty] \in \mathcal{L}(\bar{\mathbb{R}})$, and $B = [-\infty,0)$, thus $A \cap [-\infty,0) = f^{-1}([-\infty,0)) \cap [-\infty,0) \in \mathcal{L}(\bar{\mathbb{R}})$. Therefore, $A = (A \cap [0,\infty]) \cup (A \cap [-\infty,0)) \in \mathcal{L}(\bar{\mathbb{R}})$, a contradiction.

Is my approach OK? It seems to me there should be a more direct way to show failure of Lebesgue-measurability. Any ideas?

E.g., we could write
\begin{equation}
f(x) = x(1_{A}(x) - 1_{A^c}(x))
\end{equation}
where the indicator functions are non-Lebesgue-measurable. As the sum of non-Lebesgue-measurable functions, would $f$ be non-Lebesgue-measurable?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: That seems pretty simple: you assume measurability of $f$ and show that the set $A$ that was assumed nonmeasurable is a union of two sets that must be measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding non measurable functions does not necessarily imply that the result is non-measurable. Indeed $0=1_{A}  -1_{A} $.

Assume that $f$ is measurable, as you have noticed $f(x) = x(1_A(x)-1_{A^c}(x)   )$. Then $g(x)=f(x)/x$ is also measurable. However $g^{-1} ( \{1\})=A$, a contradiction. So we conclude.

Comment: Not that it really matters, but you should define $g(0)$...

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess this is exactly what I had in mind. Of course I was excluding trivial cases such as $1_A - 1_A$ and $1_A + 1_{A^c}$. So there is probably no general theorem that the sum of non-measurable functions is non-measurable, excluding these trivial cases?

Comment: @ChrisT Yes, it feels like the problem of adding two transcendental numbers, like $e-e$ is not, however $e+\pi$ we do not know.